# TYPO3 backend searches

Tags: typo3

There are two different search fields in TYPO3 backend - as in attachement.
1 - search displayed above list and page module
2 - main TYPO3 backend search
(https://ibb.co/vQZGTq0)

Does those searches use different configuration?

I have some custom table and field which I want to be searched against in case of search 1 and 2. In my table TCA I have added my field to searchFields.
I can find my record by search 2. but not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Search 1 only searches on current page, while search 2 searches within whole installation.

Therefore if you record is on a different page then currently selected, it will only be found by global search (2).

Comment: I know about that difference but that seems not to be the only difference. I am on page where my record is stored but I can not find it via search 1 while I can find it via search 2. Does search 1 uses searchFields from TCA too?

Comment: I debug it little bit and seems like TYPO3 removes some of the searchFields in list search if searched phrase can be interpreted as an integer https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7/typo3/sysext/recordlist/Classes/RecordList/AbstractDatabaseRecordList.php#L979 - which it does not remove in main search - looks strange.